# Center text in table, vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

[image: Existing]

In this image, since there are no characters like `g,y` in the first cell, there seems to be a misalignment between the round brackets and the text `CBSE`. Is there any way to automatically center text like the following image? I edited the following in GIMP and moved the text `CBSE` slightly down, to align it vertically. Is there any way to do the same in LaTeX?

[image: Requirement]

**Code snippet from my class file**

```
\begin{tabular}{|M{0.295\textwidth}|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    Program & Institute & Percent/CGPA & Year of Completion \\
    \hline
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please add some example code (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: Added the code snippet from the class file. `#1, #2, #3, #4` are filled in the main TeX file. Here, `#2` is `XII (CBSE)`

Comment: You replace one problem with another: it quite visible that `XII` and `CBSE` are not aligned.

Comment: Hi, the intended behavior was that if a cell was completely without bottom glyphs as in `g,y`, it should center the entire cell's contents. I was too lazy and just moved the `CBSE` alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug.  It is the intended behaviour.  The parentheses account for possible descenders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
(CBSE)
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to adjust vertical alignment use `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{.1333ex}{(}CBSE\raisebox{.1333ex}{)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the space automatically if there are no descenders in a word?

Comment: @KarthikNishanth No, unless you are willing to write something like `\parenthesize{CBSE}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain this result using small caps in a larger font, adding some negative kerning if you're perfectionist:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

XII (CBSE)

 \large\textsc{xii \kern-0.1em(\kern-0.07em cbse\kern-0.05em)}

 \Large\textsc{xii (cbse)}

\end{document}
```

[image]